# Dealing with bloated components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Can someone provide a clean example, or article dealing with bloated React code?
I have a HOC function on the main App.js file but I don't know how to  "redeclare" the extended component to export. Then, the other components are not sharing the render. I already have Redux on one of the components called Counter. That is working.

App.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import Actions from './components/Actions';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    countValue: state.count
  };
}

//Action

var increaseAction = { type:"increase" }
var decreaseAction = { type:"decrease" }

// Map Redux actions to component props.

function mapDispachToProps(dispach) {
  return {
    // etc..
}

// The HOC
var connectedComponent = connect (
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispachToProps
)(Counter);

export default connectedComponent;
```

Actions.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import Counter from './Components/Counter';
import './App.css';

class Actions extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    response: ''
    };

}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
        "/posts"
    )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ response: data }))
    }

    render() {

        return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
            {/* <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> */}
            {Array.isArray(this.state.response) &&
                this.state.response.map(resIndex => <div>
                <ul>
                  <App> 
                    `<Counter>` 
                      <li>{resIndex.title} </li> // <- is this not bloated?
                      <li>{resIndex.author} </li>
                    </Counter>
                  </App>
                </ul>
                </div>
            )}
            </header>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Actions;
```